# Why helper macro to fill a struct needs explicit casting?

Tags: c, macos, casting

Consider the piece of declaration:

```
struct my_cool_struc {
   int field_x;
   int field_Y;
   int field_z;
};

#define MY_COOL_MACRO(x,y,z) \
  { \
    .field_x = (x), \
    .field_y = (y), \
    .field_z = (z), \
  }

static const struct my_cool_struc why[] = {
  MY_COOL_MACRO(1,2,3),
  MY_COOL_MACRO(6,5,4),
  MY_COOL_MACRO(7,8,9),
  {}
};

static int my_cool_func(...)
{
   struct my_cool_struc p[10];
   int a1, a2, a3;
   unsigned int index = 0;
...
   p[index++] = MY_COOL_MACRO(a1, a2, a3);
...
   return 0;
}
```

While in the `why` assignment everything works fine, compiler can's build the function, fails on syntax parser.

The following fixes the issue:

```
- { \
+ (struct my_cool_struc) { \
```

or

```
- p[index++] = MY_COOL_MACRO(a1, a2, a3);
+ p[index++] = (struct my_cool_struc)MY_COOL_MACRO(a1, a2, a3);
```

Compiler is GCC (different versions) on Linux.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i think that you second version is a compound literal (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) while the fist one is just invalid code.

Comment: You get syntax errors because that's invalid syntax for assigning to a structure. Initialization and assignment are two very different things.

Comment: @SisterFister, first case works nice w/o any errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, any pointers to documentation? Moreover, the question is why the first case is okay, while second one fails. In both cases lvalue has a defined type.

Comment: With first and second I meant the vesions before and after your patch.

Comment: @SisterFister, ah, okay, see my last comment to Dude.

Comment: E.g. `{.a = x, .b = y}` is not a structure, it's an initialization list. `(struct some_struct){.a = x, .b = y}` on the other hand *is* a structure, it's a [*compound literal*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). See [this C language reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language) for more information, or [read some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/440558).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks, got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MY_COOL_MACRO` when used in the declaration, is using *designated initializers*, which is a feature only existing during initialization. They cannot be used during assignment.

The reason why `(struct my_cool_struc)MY_COOL_MACRO` fixes the problem during assignment, is because it is not a cast at all. Rather, it is creating a temporary, unnamed object known as *compound literal*:

```
(struct my_cool_struc){ .field_x = (x), .field_y = (y), .field_z = (z) }
```

And since you are creating an object, the part between `{ }` is an initializer list, where you can use designated initializers.

You then assign the compound literal to your array item in run-time, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yep, I have got it. How does the fix I posted (variant 1) affect initialization of constant `why`?

Comment: @0andriy Not at all, it is redundant and will get optimized away. It is basically the same as writing `int x = (int){ 5 };` rather than just `int x = 5;`. The compound literal in this case adds nothing and makes the code harder to read.